# How to read a non linear skb in a ebpf program attached to kprobe hook

Tags: ebpf

If the skb is non linear, is there a way I can linearize the skb data in an ebpf program attached to a kprobe hook?.

It seems helpers such as bpf_skb_pull_data are not available at tracepoints. Is there another way if I need to read the required data?

Comment: Where is your kprobe attached?

Comment: @pchaigno I was planning to attach at icmp_send or icmp_push_reply to get the ingress skb information in case of error

Comment: Is there any reason why bpf_skb_load_bytes is not available as helpers for tracepoints/kprobe hooks?. I can understand bpf_skb_pull_data since it changes the skb pointers but was wondering about bpf_skb_load_bytes..

Comment: What would the use case be? There is already bpf_probe_read_kernel to read from kernel memory.

Comment: Its to read non linear parts from skbuff which we cannot do via bpf_probe_read_kernel as I understand.